# cx_Oracle on linux: ImportError: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: cx-oracle

I'm having problems using cx_Oracle on a linux system. I get the error message: `libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

What exactly do I need to install to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an Oracle client. The simplest is the Oracle Instant client which you can download from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html

Follow the instructions at the bottom of the page for the specific platform you are using. If you are using an RPM based distribution you can simply install the RPMs which do all of the dirty work for you!